# How to add Woocomrce cart page shipping calculator to my country state list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Im beginner for the word press , 
I don't know if the issue is because of the  . The problem is that the "calculate shipping" option on my cart page doesn't allow users to select my country / state list, only allowed  postal code

i want to know How to add Woocomrce cart page shipping calculator to my country state list, reason my  country state list not here

example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this snippet to the `functions.php` file of your theme to add a new country to the WooCommerce countries list.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_states', 'sa_woocommerce_states');
add_filter('woocommerce_countries_allowed_country_states','sa_woocommerce_state');

function SA_woocommerce_states( $states ) {

    $states['ZA']['EC'] = __('Eastern Cape', 'woocommerce');
    return $states;
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir, whare's to put Dubai > state list

Comment: ok i edit code please wait

Comment: sir, i added this its not working ,selected state option are empty

Comment: you add state in code

Comment: is it correct ? `function custom_woocommerce_states( $Dubai ) {

$states['Dubai'] = array( 'Dubai' => 'State 1', 'Dubai => 'State 2' );

return $states;

}`

Comment: please try this plugin :https://wordpress.org/plugins/states-cities-and-places-for-woocommerce/

Comment: i am edit code please try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86375/discussion-between-core114-and-vikrant-zilpe).