# wooCommerce checkout page State / County (optional) validate not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, validation

wooCommerce checkout page **State / County (optional)** validate not working

that is my added code

```
 add_filter(‘thwcfd_State_field_override_required’,’__return_true’);
```

any idea for how to add mandatory for the **State / County (optional)**

like as `State / County (optional)*`

look my issue

[image]

Comment: hi ok i send solution for you

Comment: please send state/ country field name

Comment: See this, function SA_woocommerce_states( $states ) {

`$states['LK']['CK'] = __('Colombo', 'woocommerce');
 $states['LK']['RT'] = __('Kandy', 'woocommerce');
return $states;
}`

Comment: Sri, yesterday you given n some solution for me, look https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320546/how-to-add-woocomrce-cart-page-shipping-calculator-to-my-country-state-list

Comment: this shipping form?

Comment: please come with chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86433/discussion-between-core114-and-vikrant-zilpe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code goes in `function.php` file of your active child theme (or active theme). It could works.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'woo_filter_state_billing', 10, 1 ); 
function woo_filter_state_billing( $address_fields ) { 
    $address_fields['billing_state']['required'] = true;
    return $address_fields; 
} 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'woo_filter_state_shipping', 10, 1 );
function woo_filter_state_shipping( $address_fields ) { 
    $address_fields['shipping_state']['required'] = true; 
    return $address_fields; 
}
```

Comment: hello sir, sorry its not working , i want to validate ``State / County (optional)` please check my updated question

Comment: ok i check and send new update