# Show only geolocated user country into Woocommerce checkout country fields

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks

**What I'm NOT trying to do:**

- Remove or hide checkout (billing/shipping) country fields

**What I'm trying do to:**

- Show only ONE country in checkout (billing/shipping) country fields, depending on geolocation (geolocation is already done)
- OR, Remove countries I don't want to show to user from checkout (billing/shipping) country fields

**Facts:**

- My Woocommerce Selling Location(s) settings are: Germany, Andorra, Austria, Bulgaria, Belgium, Croatia, Denmark, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Estonia, Finland, France, Greece, Hungary, Ireland, Latvia, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Monaco, Netherlands, Poland, Portugal, United Kingdom (UK), Czech Republic, Romania, Sweden and Switzerland
- I want to sell to all of these countries, so removing countries from Selling Location(s) list is not a solution.
- I need a hook/filter solution, please.

**What have I've done so far:**

- I've tried out several hooks/filters to achieve that: `woocommerce_checkout_get_value`, `woocommerce_shipping_fields`, `woocommerce_billing_fields`, `woocommerce_default_address_fields` and `woocommerce_checkout_fields`. None of them seems to work...

**Code I've written:**

```
// NOT WORKING! SHOWS ALL Selling Location(s) (allowed countries)
function override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] = array(
        'type'         => 'country',
        'label'        => __( 'Country / Region', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'country',
        'priority'     => 40,
        'options'      => array( $user_country_code => __( $user_country_name, 'woocommerce' ) )
    );
    
    //Same for billing_country...
    
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );

// NOT WORKING! SHOWS ALL Selling Location(s) (allowed countries)
function edit_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_country'] = array(
        'type'         => 'country',
        'label'        => __( 'Country / Region', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'country',
        'priority'     => 40,
        'options'      => array( $user_country_code => __( $user_country_name, 'woocommerce' ) )
    );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'edit_billing_fields' );

... And more
```

**NOTE:** If I change `'type' => 'country'` by `'type' => 'select'` it works, but then if I change country (showing two countries for testing), the state dropdown do not update whith the states for that new selected country. Also the dropdown is shown without Select2 appeareance.

**Further Explanation:**
I am selling now to 28 countries. For example, if a user is accessing the web from France, when the user arrives at checkout form, I only want to let you send the product to France. This is the reason why I want to show only the user country (previously geolocated) in the (billing/shipping) country dropdown.

I would appreciate your help! Thanks

Comment: I believe, there is no 'type' as 'country'. 
Can you change 'type' to 'text' and apply a css class that will make it disabled ?

Answer (score 1):

If `'type' => 'select'` works for you then to solve state selection, you can try `woocommerce_states` and `woocommerce_countries_allowed_country_states` filter to list states only for the user's country.

Reference : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/320548/163113

Comment: Hi @ViralP! Appreciate your time to answer the question. Yes, I could do it as the way you say. But also, I've found another way, through the filter `woocommerce_countries_allowed_countries`. I'll show you that in a new answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it by focusing to a different filter, one that doesn't have to do with the checkout directly. The filter in question is `woocommerce_countries_allowed_countries`. This filter is in the `get_allowed_countries()` function and gets the countries the store sells to. So limiting the countries the store sells to, I fix the country listing problem at checkout. In this way, a french user will only see France in the country dropdown, an australian user will only see Australia in the country dropdown and so on... Here is the code:

```
/**
 * @param array $countries
 * @return array
 */
function custom_update_allowed_countries( $countries ) {

    // Only on frontend
    if( is_admin() ) return $countries;

    if( class_exists( 'WC_Geolocation' ) ) {
        $location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();

        if ( isset( $location['country'] ) ) {
            $countryCode = $location['country'];
        } else {
            // If there is no country, then return allowed countries
            return $countries;
        }
    } else {
        // If you can't geolocate user country by IP, then return allowed countries
        return $countries;
    }

    // If everything went ok then I filter user country in the allowed countries array
    $user_country_code_array = array( countryCode );

    $intersect_countries = array_intersect_key( $countries, array_flip( $user_country_code_array ) );

    return $intersect_countries;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_allowed_countries', 'custom_update_allowed_countries', 30, 1 );
```